# Vb.NET Type 'Public member 'Transpose' on type 'Application' not found.'

Tags: excel, vb.net, arraylist, range

I am opening Excel using VB.NET and trying to make 1D arraylist from a column that contains value "Filename" using the code:

```
xlApp = New Excel.Application With {
    .DisplayAlerts = False
}
xlApp.Visible = False
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("G:\Items Library Database.xlsm")
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

'Array "Filename"
Column_Number = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find("Filename", LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole)
Column_Letter = Chr(Column_Number.Column + 64)

ItemFileNameArray = xlApp.Transpose(xlWorkSheet.Range(Column_Letter & "1:" & Column_Letter  & LastRow).Value)
```

And the thread title suggests - it returns 'Public member 'Transpose' on type 'Application' not found.'

How do you make a 1D arraylist from excel column?

Comment: Why do you expect a method called `Transpose`?  What is the type of `xlApp` and where is that method defined/documented?

Comment: Because it's what worked for me in VBA but now I need to get that same thing working in VB.NET. Regarding ~~xlapp~~ - edited OP

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in VBA, it's not a function on the Application object.

Comment: What is it then?

Comment: The Excel VBA reference is pretty good, as I recall, so I would recommend consulting it to confirm.  I would expect, though, that it would be a method on a Worksheet and/or a Range.

Comment: As for the Transpose not found error, try accessing it via `xlWorkBook.Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose()`.